# Solving $\sin(f(x))=g\left(x\right)$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

This may be a very dumb question but whenever I try to look it up all my results are about derivatives and integrals. Is there any general way of just solving the equation $\sin(f(x))=g(x)$ for $x$? Currently I'm trying to solve

$$\frac{\sqrt{x-9}\sqrt{x-1}-3}{x}=\sin\left(\frac{3\sqrt{x-9}+\sqrt{x-1}}{2x}\right)$$

and don't know even the first step. Let's just define $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x-9}\sqrt{x-1}-3}{x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{3\sqrt{x-9}+\sqrt{x-1}}{2x}$ so I don't have to keep writing everything out. The only method I can think of is to do the following:

$$f(x) = \sin(g(x))$$

$$\arcsin(f(x)) = g(x)$$

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}} \, dx = g(x)$$

And just pray that there is a second way to integrate the left and end up with a solvable equation. Is there are good way to do this that I'm missing? Sorry again if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Surely $x\ge 9$. A casual look at the graphs: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Sqrt%28x-9%29sqrt%28x-1%29-3%29%2Fx , https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Sqrt%28x-9%29%2B3sqrt%28x-1%29%29%2F%282x%29 : looks like $g(x)$ increases in $[9,10]$, decreases in $[10,\infty)$, and stays positive but small $(0\le g(x)\le 1/2)$. $f(x)$ is negative in $[9,10]$ so cannot be the $\sin$ of $g(x)$. On $[10,\infty)$, $\sin(g(x))$ decreases with increasing $x$ (and decreasing $g(x)$), and $f(x)$ increases, so there will be at most one solution, which you may be able to find numerically.

Comment: Otherwise, no, there is no general method that would work for any $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop dang that kinda stinks. It's wild how something that seems so simple is impossible, no?

Comment: Any correct second way to integrate the left cannot give an answer other than $\arcsin f(x)$, or an equivalent expression which probably could have been shown equivalent in a simpler way.

Comment: Also note even much simpler equations like $\sin x = \frac{x}{2}$ have solutions which can't be written with common expressions.